# ruby haml don't get the results I want (beginner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm struggling with haml not injecting the content at the right place, here is part of the haml :

```
%div.form-group{:id => 'container'}
- if !@data.nil?
  %p= t('users.data_name')
  = link_to t('users.delete'), 'javascript:void(0)', :class => 'delete', :data => {:id => @data.id}
  %div.holder.thick
    = image_tag @data.path
- else
  = link_to t('users.upload'), 'javascript:void(0)', :class => 'btn btn-large'
  %div.holder
    = image_tag '/assets/missing_image.png'
```

The problem is that the `holder` or `holder thick` are not inside my container but outside. Why is this? What am I not aligning properly?

Comment: http://html2haml.heroku.com/

Comment: instead of `%div.holder`, use `.holder`, and replace `%div.form-group{:id => 'container'}` with `#container.form-group`, `%div.holder.thick` should be `.holder.thick`

Comment: http://haml2erb.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `if` should be indented if its content is meant to go into `#container`.

```
#container.form-group
  - if !@data.nil?
    %p= t('users.data_name')
    = link_to t('users.delete'), 'javascript:void(0)', :class => 'delete', :data => {:id => @data.id}
    .holder.thick
      = image_tag @data.path
  - else
    = link_to t('users.upload'), 'javascript:void(0)', :class => 'btn btn-large'
    .holder
      = image_tag '/assets/missing_image.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

if your container is `%div.form-group` then you have just to indent the rest so that haml understands it's inside that div that your content should go

so it'll look like that

```
%div.form-group{:id => 'container'}
  - if !@data.nil?
    %p= t('users.data_name')
    = link_to t('users.delete'), 'javascript:void(0)', :class => 'delete', :data => {:id => @data.id}
    %div.holder.thick
      = image_tag @data.path
  - else
    = link_to t('users.upload'), 'javascript:void(0)', :class => 'btn btn-large'
    %div.holder
      = image_tag '/assets/missing_image.png'
```